# RESTful API 404 to success is it right?

Tags: node.js, rest

I am building an API on NodeJS and I would like to use the correct HTTP returns for the created interfaces. I am using the placements indicated on the sites:

My question:
I built the "checkEmail" API with ajax. The page calls the server, which checks whether the email entered by the user exists or not. Theoretically, when a resource is not found, I should return a 404. If the email does not exist, I return a 404 - which in this case is a success for the user (he can use this email). However, if an email exists, I return a 200. This, for purposes of the screen, returns an error because the email is already in use and the user will have to enter another one. The last case would be if the user entered an invalid email. In this case I return a 500, stating that the content you entered is not a valid email.

Is this logic correct? I am in doubt as I am using 404 for success (in this case) and 200 for failure (email found - already used).

Thanks.

Comment: You should use a success response whenever the request is valid and, in fact a success. If you want to validate that an email does NOT exist and it actually doesn't exist, it's a success, so you return 200. If it exists it's not a success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 should used for server errors only (Like an internal exception) where as 400 errors imply client error such as invalid input. For invalid email, that would be a 400 family since the client could change the input email and it may succeed.

For an object that doesn't exist in a database, there is a debate on whether it should be a 20x or a 404. I personally don't like 404 just for missing objects in a database for an API since it could also look like the route doesn't exist. (i.e. I types in /user/1234 instead of userS/1234 when the routes was defined as /users/{id}. Most frameworks now have a 404 catch all if the route template doesn't exist which may need my attention. Same goes for reverse proxies in the middle that could be routing to different API servers. I like knowing from a quick glance if the route template is correct and that the object is just doesn't exist in a Db.

So this brings up which 200. You could use 204 (No Content), which means the body doesn't have any content (But that doesn't imply the database doesn't). Many use this for a DELETE which doesn't return the deleted object back. 204 has more meaning in browsers rather than a pure AJAX API, but it definitly works. You could also use just a plan 200.

Answer (score -2):

500 is used for server error and 40- for user errors i suggest 200 for bot cases found and not but changing body result